# rsync over ssh tunnel: What does this repeated message mean? debug2: channel 2: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072

Tags: rsync, ssh-tunnel

I'm `rsync`ing through an SSH tunnel (with ssh -vv). It's not very fast and I'm getting this message about every second:

```
debug2: channel 2: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
```

Once in a while I also get this message:

```
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 98345
```

What do these messages mean and is there a way to speed up my transfer?